# Input field does not save decimal numbers and sets it to ,00

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this input field in a website I have to fix. In this input field I need custom decimal numbers, but when I typ in 36,82 and press save. It says 36,00.

Code :

```
  <tr>
    <td>Btw tarief: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="tarief_btw" id="tarief_btw" value="<? $tarief_btw = $tarief_btw*100; $tarief_btw=number_format($tarief_btw, 2, ',', ''); echo $tarief_btw ?>"></td>
  </tr>
```

Edit *1 :

better question : How can I fill in 32,68 then format it to 32.68 save that and then change it back to 32,68 when its saved

Comment: What type is your field in the database?

Comment: Try with a dot : 36.82

Comment: "Btw tarief:" should be a `<label>`. http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html

Comment: double values are sepparetet with **.** (dot) and not with , in mysql, php

Answer (score 0):

Decimals in PHP a JS are with `.`, not `,`.

When you save them into database, you can replace `,` for `.`.

```
$decimal = str_replace(',', '.', $decimal);
```